# Automatic indentation of HTML output?

Tags: php, html, indentation

I would like to automatically indent the HTML outputted by the PHP script.

I do use HTML Purifier for internal textbox input form validation, and have considered HTMLTidy. However, as the HTML purifier depends on HTML Tidy, which is not developed actively and there are a lot of bugs reported, I was looking for something else.

I have found:

https://github.com/gajus/dindent

Is this a good choice? - Is there another script or way to process the output?

As is, I am doing indentation in a quite a laborious way, for example (part of the function that takes indentation argument):

```
echo str_repeat("\t", $indentation) . "<ul>\n";
foreach($result as $value)
    {
    echo str_repeat("\t", $indentation) . "\t<li>" . datetime_converter($value["Date"]) . " - " . $value["Article"] . "</li>\n";
    }
echo str_repeat("\t", $indentation) . "</ul>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: The external script comments are just for the purpose of illustration to describe that I've done my homework! - I received a good reply below, I just need to make it working, so please unlock this.

Comment: The below script solved the problem!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my indentation function, hope it helps.

```
class Html {
    private static $_indent = "  ";

    private static function indentStr($indentlevel = 0){
        $replaceindent = null;

        //Sets the indentation from current indentlevel
        for($o = 0; $o < $indentlevel; $o++) {
            $replaceindent .= self::$_indent;
        }

        return $replaceindent;
    }

    public static function indent($uncleanhtml) {   
        // Seperate tags
        $uncleanhtml_array = explode("<", $uncleanhtml);
        $uncleanhtml_array = array_filter($uncleanhtml_array);
        foreach($uncleanhtml_array as $unfixedtextkey => $unfixedtextvalue) {
            if(!trim($unfixedtextvalue)){
                continue;
            }

            $unfixedtextvalue = '<' . trim($unfixedtextvalue);

            //Makes sure empty lines are ignores
            if(!preg_match("/^(\s)*$/", $unfixedtextvalue)) {
                $fixedtextvalue = preg_replace("/>(\s|\t)*</U", ">\n<", $unfixedtextvalue);
                $uncleanhtml_array[$unfixedtextkey] = $fixedtextvalue;
            }

        }

        //Sets no indentation
        $indentlevel = 0;
        foreach($uncleanhtml_array as $uncleanhtml_key => $currentuncleanhtml) {
            //Removes all indentation
            $currentuncleanhtml = preg_replace("/\t+/", "", $currentuncleanhtml);
            $currentuncleanhtml = preg_replace("/^\s+/", "", $currentuncleanhtml);

            $replaceindent = self::indentStr($indentlevel);

            //If self-closing tag, simply apply indent
            if(preg_match("/<(.+)\/>/", $currentuncleanhtml)) { 
                $cleanhtml_array[$uncleanhtml_key] = $replaceindent.$currentuncleanhtml;
            } else if(preg_match("/<!(.*)>/", $currentuncleanhtml)) { 
                //If doctype declaration, simply apply indent
                $cleanhtml_array[$uncleanhtml_key] = $replaceindent.$currentuncleanhtml;
            } else if(preg_match("/<[^\/](.*)>/", $currentuncleanhtml) && preg_match("/<\/(.*)>/", $currentuncleanhtml)) {
                //If opening AND closing tag on same line, simply apply indent 
                $cleanhtml_array[$uncleanhtml_key] = $replaceindent.$currentuncleanhtml;
            } else if(preg_match("/<\/(.*)>/", $currentuncleanhtml) || preg_match("/^(\s|\t)*\}{1}(\s|\t)*$/", $currentuncleanhtml)) {
                //If closing HTML tag or closing JavaScript clams, decrease indentation and then apply the new level
                $indentlevel--;
                $replaceindent = self::indentStr($indentlevel);

                $cleanhtml_array[$uncleanhtml_key] = $replaceindent.$currentuncleanhtml;
            } else if((preg_match("/<[^\/](.*)>/", $currentuncleanhtml) && !preg_match("/<(link|meta|base|br|img|hr|\?)(.*)>/", $currentuncleanhtml)) || preg_match("/^(\s|\t)*\{{1}(\s|\t)*$/", $currentuncleanhtml)) {
                //If opening HTML tag AND not a stand-alone tag, or opening JavaScript clams, increase indentation and then apply new level
                $cleanhtml_array[$uncleanhtml_key] = $replaceindent.$currentuncleanhtml;

                $indentlevel++;
                $replaceindent = self::indentStr($indentlevel);
            } else{
                //Else, only apply indentation
                $cleanhtml_array[$uncleanhtml_key] = $replaceindent.$currentuncleanhtml;
            }
        }

        //Return single string seperated by newline
        return implode("\n", $cleanhtml_array); 
    }
}
```

And you call this like:

```
Html::indent($uncleanhtml);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. - Is there a special way to invoke this function? (I am a beginner.) I am getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)"