# Don't output indent before PHP open tag

Tags: php, html, indentation

I am trying to style my PHP script like a templating language, but the problem is, that PHP outputs the indentation before `<?php` tags like this:

```php
<ul>
    <? foreach ($arr as $val) { ?>
        <li><?= $val ?></li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

This works, but outputs

```html
<ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
    </ul>
```

and that is terrible.

Is there a way to not output the indentation before PHP tags?

---

Secondly, the `<li>` tag is indented twice, but I want to remove one indentation level.

Is that possible?

Comment: _"and that is terrible"_ - why? Who cares what the HTML source code looks like? _"Is that possible?"_ - no, PHP does not provide any mechanism for that by default. You would have to parse & modify your generated output afterwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075174/automatic-indentation-of-html-output

Comment: @CBroe I care about HTML source. I don't want it to look like some random CMS system output.

Comment: @JordiNebot that is interesting, but I'm not generating my HTML using strings, as you can see in my example.

Comment: *"I don't want it to look like some random CMS system output"* — That's what it is though. It would make the most sense to put the result through a minifier to remove all non-essential whitespace. Frankly: trying to produce pretty output from a PHP template is not realistic and too much of a headache to be worth worrying about in practice. If you really care about this enough, use another template system which explicitly enables this, or explicitly feed the result of this through a prettifier. Trying to handle it manually within the template is practically hopeless.

Comment: I already thought about using a minifier, that might be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP starting tag "<?php" must be under UL tag no indent. this will work.

```
<ul>
<?php
     foreach ($arr as $val) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $val; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: So that is going to be the only way? Ok, then I will have to stick with that.